# JavaScript Accordion Menu with querySelectorAll()

Tags: javascript, toggle, accordion, custom-data-attribute, selectors-api

I'm attempting to build an accordion menu using `querySelectorAll()` but unsure what the best method would be to check if the *clicked list item's children* (`.toggleContent` and `.toggleIcon`) belong to it's clicked parent `toggle_li[i]`.

Correct me if I am wrong, but I assume that controlling this within the `onclick` function will be more flexible than impacting the `toggleDataAttr` function?

I'm still new to querySelector so any guidance is appreciated.

codepen: http://codepen.io/seejaeger/pen/qdqxGy

```
// data attribute toggle
var toggleDataAttr = function (toggleElem, opt1, opt2, dataAttr) {
  //
  // ? belongs to clicked element (parent toggle_li[i])?
  //
  var toggleElem = document.querySelector(toggleElem);

  toggleElem.setAttribute(dataAttr,
  toggleElem.getAttribute(dataAttr) === opt1 ? opt2 : opt1);
};

// declare toggle onclick element
var toggle_li = document.querySelectorAll('li');

// iterate query and listen for clicks
for (var i = 0; i < toggle_li.length; i++) {

  toggle_li[i].onclick = function() {
    //
    // ? belongs to clicked element (parent toggle_li[i])?
    //
    toggleDataAttr('.toggleContent', 'closed', 'open', 'data-state');
    toggleDataAttr('.toggleIcon', 'plus', 'minus', 'data-icon');
    };
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y38ty4w2/3/

Comment: thanks for the fiddle @Arun P Johny, interesting approach, but I ended up going with Tahir's suggestion.

Comment: I've made some big changes to my codepen as I needed to target the `<i>` within the `<li>` instead. I have the toggle script working well enough for use, but would like to come up with something DRYer. Interested in hearing anyones' thoughts on this...

Comment: @jaegs, well for one I don't think you need to pass `closed`, `open` & `data-state` strings as parameters. These are well known and can either be stored globally or locally to your `toggleDataAttr` as variables. They are *constants* per say.

Comment: Also, your `toggleContent` can be assigned by using `nextElementSibling` so `var toggleContent = iconElem.parentElement.nextElementSibling;` should help. [Browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) is from IE9 though.

Comment: @jaegs, [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/2x6Lx62k/) of what I am proposing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I think you should do:

- Update your `toggleDataAttr` function to receive one more parameter `parentElem`.
- Use this new `parentElem` for `querySelector` instead of `document` inside `toggleDataAttr`.
- And then in your loop, pass `this` as parameter to be used as `parentElem`.

***Snippet:***

```js
var toggleDataAttr = function(parentElem, toggleElem, opt1, opt2, dataAttr) {
  var toggleElem = parentElem.querySelector(toggleElem);
  toggleElem.setAttribute(dataAttr, toggleElem.getAttribute(dataAttr) === opt1 ? opt2 : opt1);
};

var toggle_li = document.querySelectorAll('li');

for (var i = 0; i < toggle_li.length; i++) {
  toggle_li[i].onclick = function() {
    toggleDataAttr(this, '.toggleContent', 'closed', 'open', 'data-state');
    toggleDataAttr(this, '.toggleIcon', 'plus', 'minus', 'data-icon');
  };
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #034;
  opacity: 0.9;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 24px;
  width: 30%;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #333;
}
li {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 0px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #aaa;
}
i {
  font-style: normal;
}
.li-label {
  padding: 18px;
}
.toggleContent {
  padding: 18px 14px;
  border-top: 2px solid #bac;
  background: #334;
  color: #eee;
}
.toggleContent[data-state=closed] {
  display: none;
}
.toggleContent[data-state=open] {
  display: block;
}
.toggleIcon[data-icon=plus]:after {
  content: '+';
  float: right;
}
.toggleIcon[data-icon=minus]:after {
  content: '-';
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="li-label">
      list item one <i class="toggleIcon" data-icon="plus"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="toggleContent" data-state="closed">toggle content one</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="li-label">
      list item two <i class="toggleIcon" data-icon="plus"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="toggleContent" data-state="closed">toggle content two</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="li-label">
      list item three <i class="toggleIcon" data-icon="plus"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="toggleContent" data-state="closed">toggle content three</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks @Tahir, your solution made me better understand how to navigate the DOM with querySelector!